# How to implement DivideByInt

Tags: f#

I'm trying to write a custom [DivideByInt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/languageprimitives.dividebyint%5B%5Et%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) as follows

```
type Pair = Pair of int * int with
    static member DivideByInt pair int = pair


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    LanguagePrimitives.DivideByInt (Pair(1,2)) 1 
    |> ignore 
    0

// compiler error: "FS0001: Method or object constructor 'DivideByInt' not found"
```

Why's the compiler not finding Pair.DivideByInt?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Pair.DivideByInt` has to take a tuple as input

the corrected version:

```
type Pair = Pair of int * int with
    static member DivideByInt (pair, int) = pair
```

Comment: I want to call LanguagePrimitives.DivideByInt  (which does exist, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/languageprimitives.dividebyint%5B%5Et%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D)

Answer (score 2):

The type `int` is not a good starting point since it doesn't support `DivideByInt` but you can make the type generic:

```
type Pair<'t> = Pair of 't * 't with
    static member inline DivideByInt (Pair (x, y), i:int) =
        Pair (LanguagePrimitives.DivideByInt x i, LanguagePrimitives.DivideByInt y i)


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    LanguagePrimitives.DivideByInt (Pair (1.0, 2.0)) 1 |> ignore 
    LanguagePrimitives.DivideByInt (Pair (1m , 2m )) 1 |> ignore 
    0
```

Otherwise you can "force" it to work over pair of ints and keep it generic:

```
type Pair<'t> = Pair of 't * 't with
    static member inline DivideByInt (Pair (x, y), i:int) =
        Pair (LanguagePrimitives.DivideByInt x i, LanguagePrimitives.DivideByInt y i)
    static member DivideByInt (Pair (x:int, y:int), i:int) =
        Pair (x / i, y / i)
    static member DivideByInt (Pair (x:uint32, y:uint32), i:int) =
        Pair (x / uint32 i, y / uint32 i)
```

Answer (score -1):

That works for me:

```
LanguagePrimitives.DivideByInt 3.0 4
|> printfn "%A"
```

So it doesn't get tuple, but two arguments. The above gives result: 0.75

Comment: LanguagePrimitives.DivideByInt takes two arguments, but Pair.DivideByInt needs to take a tuple